# Wrong characters On GO witn UBUNTU 12.04 and Oracle

Tags: oracle, go, ubuntu-12.04

I've got set up a machine with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS(64bits), Go 1.2.2 and go-oci8(github.com/mattn/go-oci8), but when I executed a query on Database Oracle 11G, it returned wrong characters on Russian and chinese.

I've tried to set up the  NLS_LANG field on my proyect as is show it below:

```
os.Setenv("NLS_LANG", "SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.AL32UTF8")
os.Setenv("NLS_LANG", "AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8")
os.Setenv("NLS_LANG", "RUSSIAN_CIS.AL32UTF8")
```

Someone can help me, what configuration of NLS_LANG I should put to get the right characters on Russian, Chinese or other difference languages than English and Spanish?

This is the example:

1.

```
Create table room 
{
  name_spainish varchar2(100),
  name_chinesses varchar2(100),
  name_russian varchar2(100)
}
```

2.

```
insert into room (name_spainish, name_chinesses, name_russian) values ('Habitación doble','雙人房','двухместный номер')
```

3.

```
package main

import (
  "database/sql"
  "fmt"
  "os"
  _ "github.com/mattn/go-oci8"
)

func main() {
   ExecQuery("select name_spainish, name_chinesses, name_russian from room")
 }

func ExecQuery(query string){
os.Setenv("NLS_LANG", "AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8")

db, err := sql.Open("oci8", "user/userps@host:1521/SID")
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err)
   return
}
rows, err := db.Query(query)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err)
   return
}

for rows.Next() {
    var nameSpainish string
    var nameChinesses string
    var nameRussian string
    rows.Scan(&nameSpainish, &nameChinesses, &nameRussian)
    fmt.Printf("Name Spainish %s - Name Chinesses %s - Name Russian %s", nameSpainish, nameChinesses, nameRussian)
}
rows.Close()
db.Close()
}
```

**current output:**
Habitación doble ???? ?????????

**expect output:**
Habitación doble 雙人房 двухместный номер

Comment: What do you mean with "wrong characters"? Please elaborate.

Comment: @FUZxxl The query should returned chinesse characters like 僅住宿 and Russian like Только размещение , but I get ¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ .

Comment: Can you upload a working example of the problem ? It might be your machine configuration

Comment: @CarlosAndresGarcía That's strange. Could you post some code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: try inserting the names into string literals, and compare them within the code. That way you can rule out other environment issues.

Comment: @JimB I've tried putting literals like you recommend  (select 'Habitación doble' , '雙人房', 'двухместный номер' from room) , but I received the same answer (Habitación doble ???? ?????????).

Comment: I mean *compare* them in the code, not just print them. You can also take a look at the actual bytes returned, e.g. if you're getting something like `\xd9\x96` for 雙, then it's utf16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem had been solved converting the values into hexadecimal  using the follow query

```
select RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(name_spainish, name_chinesses, name_russian)) from room
```

On code was adding the package encoding/hex and the function hex.DecodeString(texto).

```
for rows.Next() {
    var nameSpainish string
    var nameChinesses string
    var nameRussian string
    rows.Scan(&nameSpainish, &nameChinesses, &nameRussian)
    dataSpainish, _ := hex.DecodeString(nameSpainish)
    dataChinesses, _ := hex.DecodeString(nameChinesses)
    dataRussian, _ := hex.DecodeString(nameRussian)
    fmt.Printf("Name Spainish %s - Name Chinesses %s - Name Russian %s", string(dataSpainish), string(dataChinesses), string(dataRussian))
}
```